# Determine deltas between new extract and data extracted by previous run and Generate three separate CSV feed files based on the deltas

Tags: etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter, information-extraction

Hi I have a requirement which I need to develop in Informatica. 
The requirement is 
1)Determine deltas between new extract and data extracted by previous run 
2) Generate three separate CSV feed files based on the deltas

Could you please let me know the process of how to do this delta thing and compare the data from previous run and the new run 
And how to write these delta data into an automated .csv file which need to be created automatically by informatica for every run .
Instead of writing the data into target table,it should write the data into these automated .csv or .txt files.
Does Informatica creates .csv or .txt files automatically and saves the data in them for every informatica run?if so, could you please let me know how?

Comment: Hi Raj. Briefly speaking: yes, that's possible in Informatica. But don't expect people to do your job for you. Make some effort and seek help here with particular problems. I'm sure people here will help you solve them and answer any questions.

Answer (score 0):

Information you are seeking is widely available on the Internet and can be found with little research. However, let me try to chip in,

1. If the structure of the file remains the same between two runs, create two staging tables, one for previous and one for current. Do a minus between the two to capture the delta. Move the current to previous after delta capture and truncate current every time you load into it.
2. Use a flat file target instead of a table.